# About to solve simulating click on Href anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser

I was looking for a way to simulate a click on `<a>` tag

as you all know , no success ( the only workaround is by `window.open`...)

however i found some peaces of code in the net and managed to make it work in :

http://jsbin.com/itujek/5/edit

```
Chrome
IE
```

the problem is with FF.

I'll be glad to share the code with you , and towards a solution which will wrk in FF.

what should i do in this code in order for this code wo work with FF ?

```
  <script>
        function doClick(event, myA)
        {
            if (myA.click)
            {
                myA.click()
            }
            else if (document.createEvent)
            {
                if (event.target !== myA)
                {
                    var tmpEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                    tmpEvent.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                    var allowDefault = myA.dispatchEvent(tmpEvent);
                }
            }
        }


      $(document).ready(function(){

            $(".myBtn").on('click',function (event) 
                           { doClick(event, $("#link")[0]);    });
      });



    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="link" href="http://www.msdn.com">Normal link</a>
    <button type="button" class="myBtn"   >
        do click</button>
    <br />
    <br />
</body>
```

Comment: So the problem is with FireFox... any clues on what it's doing to be a problem? You'll need to explain before anyone can answer.

Comment: @BenEverard the problem is that `Firefox will *not* redirect to myA.href`

Comment: Have you tried $("#link").trigger("click");`? Also, your param is called `event`, but your code uses `e.target`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no.... ( just kidding man , thats the first thing ive tried. ) the click is working if you bind your own click method . but if you dont - it wont activate as if you pressed the anchor.

Comment: Hey the jsbin example works for me on FF 13.0.1

Comment: @Víctor you right. it does work in FF 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to use [jquery.simulate.js](https://github.com/medihack/jquery-ui/blob/ticker/tests/jquery.simulate.js) :

```
$(elem).simulate(mouse_or_keyboard_event_type, options);
```

Supported event types:

- mouse:     **mouseover, mouseout, mousedown, mouseup, mousemove, click, dblclick**
- keyboard:  **keyup, keydown, keypress**

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code here

```
if (myA.click)
{
   myA.click()
}
```

maybe your firefox element has .click attribute so it just call the function click (event) not actually do the redirect. My suggest is just remove this part and simulate a real click.
Or
You may want to simulate redirect by using `window.location.href = anchor.href`

Comment: i already wrote : the only workaround is by window.open... which i dont want...:)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if (myA.click){
    myA.click();
}
```

you can do

```
if (myA.click){
    window.location.href = myA.href;
}
```

Another thing, on the line
`if (e.target !== myA)`
the variable `e`is not defined, it should be `event`.

Comment: you right about the e. i editted. thanks.  regarding the window.location - thats the solution which i already know of ( i mentioned it on the question also)

Comment: Oh, you said `window.open`, I thought you were talking of another method, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It's for occasions like this that I prefer to avoid 'faking' events. Have you tried reding the href and redirecting to it manually? Try this:

```
$(".myBtn").on('click', function(event) {
    doClick($("#link"));
});


function doClick($el) {
    var href = $el[0].href;
    if ($el.attr("target") != "_blank") {
        window.location.assign(href );
    }
    else {
        window.open(href, "newWindow");
    }
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m6SBJ/)

Comment: currently im working on my solution which is just lie yours ( get the attr from the href and open a new window... i already mentioned this in my question that this is the only work around.... still i prefer tweaking and finding a solution)